# Unicode with Pyramid, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid and SQLAlchemy, but the following simplified code:

```
u = u"\u201C"

m = M()
m.comment = u
m.user_id = 1
session.add( m )
session.commit()
```

gives me a

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

what do I need to fix this?

edit:

comment is a "MEDIUMTEXT" column, MySQL type.

Comment: Can you post the definition of class `M`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if your database's tables are encoded with an encoding other than unicode.

Also, if you want your comments be readable from phpMyAdmin (or whatever you are using to connect to your DB) you should append:

?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0

to your connection string in the application configuration file

so you'd have mysql://user:pass@localhost/dbname?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your `comment` column should be of type `Unicode` instead of `String`.